# How to i get the questions part to align to the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

[the code when it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELvaL.png)

So far the *.cntr* class is centered by using position:relative, how do I do it automatically? If there are any code that are unnecessary please do tell as I'm still learning

Any recommendations on where i could further learn website coding, maybe any good courses you might recommend?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Fill In The Blanks</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>

        #frame001 {
            background-color: white;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: auto;
            height: 500px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #color001 {
            color: black;
            font-size: large;
            text-align: left;
        }

        #center001 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .button001 {
            margin-top: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button002 {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        #qbox{
            width: auto;
            float: left;
        }

        .cntr{
            margin: auto;
            width: 50%;
            position: relative;
            left: 350px;
       
        }

        #input{
            width: auto;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .clear{
            clear: both;;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="frame001">
        <div id="color001">
            <div id="center001">
                <h2><strong>Fill In The Blanks</strong></h2>

                <p><strong>Options:</strong> a - b - c - d - e</p>
            </div>

            <br />

            <div class="cntr">
                <div id="qbox">
                    <p class="questions"> q1</p>

                    <p class="questions">q2 </p>

                    <p class="questions"> q3 </p>

                    <p class="questions">q4 </p> 

                    <p class="questions">q5 </p>
                </div>

                <div id="input">
                    <p><input type="text" class="check003" id="input001" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check001"></text></p>

                    <p><input id="input002" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check002"></text></p>

                    <p><input id="input003" size="15" /> <text class="button002" id="check003"></text></p>

                    <p><input id="input004" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check004"></text></p>

                    <p><input id="input005" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check005"></text></p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="disappear001"><div id="center001"><button class="button001" onclick="submit001()">Submit</button></div></div><br />
            
            <div id="center001"><p id="message001"></p><p id="reload001"></p></div>
                <br />
            <br />
            </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var g;
        var h;
        var i;
        var j;
        var k;
        function submit001() {
            b = input001.value;
            c = input002.value;
            d = input003.value;
            e = input004.value;
            f = input005.value;
            if (b == "a" || b == "jerusalem") {
                g = 1;
                input001.value = b;
                check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input001.value = b;
                check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (c == "b" || c == "amman") {
                h = 1
                input002.value = c;
                check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input002.value = c;
                check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (d == "c" || d == "london") {
                i = 1;
                input003.value = d;
                check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input003.value = d;
                check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (e == "d" || e == "brasilia") {
                j = 1;
                input004.value = e;
                check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input004.value = e;
                check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (f == "e" || f == "ottawa") {
                k = 1;
                input005.value = f;
                check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input005.value = f;
                check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (g == 1 && h == 1 && i == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1) {
                message001.innerHTML = "Good :)";
                disappear001.innerHTML = "";
                reload001.innerHTML = "<div id=center001><button class=button001 onclick=repeat001()>Repeat</button></div>";
            }
        }

            function repeat001() {
                location.reload();
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to center something you can use the `<center>` tag in html or the `text-align:center` in css. Instead of courses you look at the w3schools website. They have almost every language documented in there.

Answer (score 0):

you can work with align-items: center and justify-content:center for vertical and horizontal centering.

As for learning don't rely on single source of knowledge keep exploring and pick what best suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. Using flex property we resolved your problem.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/qan837dL/

```js
var g;
        var h;
        var i;
        var j;
        var k;
        function submit001() {
            b = input001.value;
            c = input002.value;
            d = input003.value;
            e = input004.value;
            f = input005.value;
            if (b == "a" || b == "jerusalem") {
                g = 1;
                input001.value = b;
                check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input001.value = b;
                check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (c == "b" || c == "amman") {
                h = 1
                input002.value = c;
                check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input002.value = c;
                check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (d == "c" || d == "london") {
                i = 1;
                input003.value = d;
                check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input003.value = d;
                check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (e == "d" || e == "brasilia") {
                j = 1;
                input004.value = e;
                check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input004.value = e;
                check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (f == "e" || f == "ottawa") {
                k = 1;
                input005.value = f;
                check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✔" + "</text>";
            } else {
                input005.value = f;
                check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + " ✖" + "</text>";
            }

            if (g == 1 && h == 1 && i == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1) {
                message001.innerHTML = "Good :)";
                disappear001.innerHTML = "";
                reload001.innerHTML = "<div id=center001><button class=button001 onclick=repeat001()>Repeat</button></div>";
            }
        }

            function repeat001() {
                location.reload();
            }
```

```css
#frame001 {
            background-color: white;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: auto;
            height: 500px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #color001 {
            color: black;
            font-size: large;
            text-align: left;
        }

        #center001 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .button001 {
            margin-top: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button002 {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        #qbox{
            width: auto;
            float: left;
        }

        .cntr{
          overflow: hidden;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
       
        }

        #input{
            width: auto;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .clear{
            clear: both;;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Fill In The Blanks</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="frame001">
      <div id="color001">
        <div id="center001">
          <h2><strong>Fill In The Blanks</strong></h2>

          <p><strong>Options:</strong> a - b - c - d - e</p>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="cntr">
          <div id="qbox">
            <p class="questions"> q1</p>

            <p class="questions">q2 </p>

            <p class="questions"> q3 </p>

            <p class="questions">q4 </p>

            <p class="questions">q5 </p>
          </div>

          <div id="input">
            <p><input type="text" class="check003" id="input001" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check001"></text></p>

            <p><input id="input002" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check002"></text></p>

            <p><input id="input003" size="15" /> <text class="button002" id="check003"></text></p>

            <p><input id="input004" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check004"></text></p>

            <p><input id="input005" size="15" /><text class="button002" id="check005"></text></p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="disappear001">
          <div id="center001"><button class="button001" onclick="submit001()">Submit</button></div>
        </div><br />

        <div id="center001">
          <p id="message001"></p>
          <p id="reload001"></p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```